# Rails bulk insert: mark association as persisted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, bulkinsert, ruby-on-rails-6

Say you have an author and each day they publish 1000 articles (yep, crazy productive).

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :articles
end

class Article < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author
end
```

---

You fetch the articles from somewhere and update some author metainformation:

```
articles = remote_articles.map do |remote_article|
  author.articles.build(remote_article)
end

author.last_publication_date = Time.current
```

---

You want to save everything in the database for a given day in 2 queries:

1. Inserts articles.
2. Updates the author.

```
ApplicationRecord.transaction do
  Article.insert_all! articles.attributes.slice('author_id', 'title', 'text')
  author.save!
end
```

Problem is, the `author.save!` will attempt to save the same `articles` that the bulk insert already inserted, because `author.articles.build` was used.

---

Is there a way to make it so `author.articles` are marked as persisted or to explicitly not save them when calling `author.save!`?

I know I can use `Article.new author_id: author_id, ...` instead of `author.articles.build ...`, but I want the objects to be properly associated with the `author` for the remainder of the request.

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting lot of articles for an author then you should not use ActiveRecord ORM , especially when you are trying to use `insert_all!`
You only need to process you `remote_articles` array and set `author_id` for each entry and then use `insert_all!`

```
   processed_array = remote_articles.map do |remote_article |
    remote_article.slice('title', 'text').merge(author_id: author.id)
   end
   ApplicationRecord.transaction do
      Article.insert_all! processed_array #This would insert all articles, as `author_id` was set for all enteries so they are already linked with this author
      author.touch :last_publication_date
    end
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I want to use `build` explicitly. If I do it the way you suggested there are no associated `article` objects to `author` after the transaction.

Comment: You can reload article afterwards with `article.reload` if you need articles objects again , mostly insertions are slow then read. You want to use `insert_all!` , which does not instantiate AR model object , but you want to make ORM objects as well. So better way is to reload author with it's associated articles. 
If you think there would be allooot of articles then stil I would recommend to use hashes instead of AR objects for better performance.

Comment: If that helps imagine that either (1) I already have a huge codebase which creates such objects and I don't want to rewrite it to return ad-hoc attributes or (2) I don't want to run the extra select.

Comment: @ndnenkov as is stated if you want to bulk insert via `insert_all!` then you are going to need to `reload` if you want to `build` and `save!` then you are going to get n + 1 saves. It is up to you but the "extra select" is going to be a lot cheaper than the n + 1 on large datasets.